# Running local project Docker Container

Tags: docker

My first day with Docker.  I'm trying to run a local project, using a Docker Container I've created.  Would it be viewable / located on 127.0.0.1:8080 ?? I  receive the following page error when I try it

```
 The connection was reset
```

run the following

```
  sudo docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -v /home/me/public_html/project-folder   delermando/php5.3-mysql5.5
```

this returns longstring response, so assume it's running

run following

```
    sudo netstat -lpn |grep :8080
```

get response

```
  tcp6    0   0 :::8080          :::*      LISTEN      21478/docker-proxy
```

Just confused how I run projects through the container and work with them, thanks??

Comment: I'm not sure how you picked the delermando/php5.3-mysql5.5 image, but that's a 2 year old image that doesn't seem to be maintained. If you look at the [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/delermando/php5.3-mysql5.5/~/dockerfile/), it's just installing some packages on top of the rtancman/php:php53-apache22 image. If we look at [rtancman/php](https://hub.docker.com/r/rtancman/php/tags/), the php53-apache22 tag has actually been unpublished. If you just need to serve PHP, why not use the official [PHP Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/), which also comes with better instructions for usage?

Comment: ok thanks for the insight.  I need PHP 5.3 or 5.4 though and PHP image seems to only have 5.6 and above.

Comment: The official PHP image no longer provides those versions because they are past end-of-life and probably have known vulnerabilities that won't be fixed. http://php.net/supported-versions.php If you must use 5.3, a build like this one provides nicer instructions than the one you're using, and doesn't depend on unpublished tags: https://hub.docker.com/r/eugeneware/php-5.3/ It is the same as the official PHP image, but uses version 5.3.